# Not able to come out of loop in protractor typscript code

Tags: typescript, for-loop, promise, protractor, ui-automation

I am new to protractor and typescript and working on an automation test code written using these.

I created a method as

```
 private allElements = $$('.some-list li');

 public async getDateElement(calDate: string) {
     this.allElements.each(async function(element, index){
      let eDate = await element.$('p').getText();
      if( eDate === calDate){
          // I tried both these options
          return eDate // getting undefined value here 
          return element.$('p').click(); // element get clicked but not coming out of loop
      }
    });
 }
```

I tried another way with for loop but break keyword is not working here

```
public async getDateElement(calDate: string) {
for (let element of await this.allElements) {
  let eDate = await element.$('p').getText();
  if (eDate === calDate) {
    element.$('p').click();
    break;
  }
 }
}
```

So don't know, how to return or come out of for loop. I googled also and someone suggested to use try-catch block and throw an exception when dates match. Is that the only solution? If someone can provide a solution using promise that would be grateful :)

Please let me know if more information is required.

Comment: Can you try adding an await to the `element.$('p').click() command?`

Comment: `this.allElements` is an iterable, not a Promise, so why would you await it?

Comment: Wondering if looping is the right thing to do. Looks like you could filter `this.allElements` to create a collection containing the element of interest, then call `element.$('p').click()`.

Comment: @SankalanParajuli tried that but does not make any difference

Comment: You are awesome @Roamer-1888. It worked with filter and it's just one line code. Thanks. Please add this to the answer so I can accept this.

Comment: @Harry, I'll give it a go though with no means of testing I may get it wrong. If so, maybe you could edit before (kindly) accepting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is synchronous then try the following chain of protractor methods:

```
public getDateElement(calDate: string) {
    return this.allElements
    .map(element => element.$('p'))
    .filter(p => p.getText() === calDate)
    .click();
}
```

Alternatively, if `.getText()` is asynchronous, then something like this but maybe with (an async version of) the `.map()` stage as above:

```
public async geDateElement(calDate: string) {    
    return this.allElements
    .filter(async element => await element.getText() === calDate)
    .click();
}
```